# SQL Server : GROUP CONCAT with DISTINCT is sorting natural data input

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-concat, for-xml-path

I have a similar situation. I start out with a table that has data input into a column from another source. This data is comma delimited coming in. I need to manipulate the data to remove a section at the end of each. So I split the data and remove the end with the code below. (I added the ID column later to be able to sort. I also added `WITH SCHEMABINDING` later to add an XML index but nothing works. I can remove this ... and the `ID` column, but I do not see any difference one way or the other):

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_Routing]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT TOP 99.9999 PERCENT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CableID) - 1 AS ID,
        CableID AS [CableID],
        SUBSTRING(m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(8000)'), 1, 13) AS Routing
    FROM 
        (SELECT
             CableID,
             CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE([RouteNodeList], ',', '</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS xml) AS x
         FROM 
             [dbo].[Cables]) t
         CROSS APPLY 
             x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData') m (n)
         ORDER BY 
             ID)
```

Now I need to concatenate data from the `Routing` column's rows into one row grouped by another column into a column again. I have the code working except that it is reordering my data; I must have the data in the order it is input into the table as it is Cable Routing information. I must also remove duplicates. I use the following code. The `SELECT DISTINCT` removes the duplicates, but reorders the data. The `SELECT` (without `DISTINCT`) keeps the correct data order, but does NOT remove the duplicates:

```
Substring(
       (
SELECT DISTINCT ','+ x3.Routing  AS [text()] --This DISTINCT reorders the routes once concatenated.
 --SELECT  ','+ x3.Routing  AS [text()] --This without the DISTINCT does not remove duplicates.
From vw_Routing x3
Where x3.CableID = c.CableId
For XML PATH ('')
       ), 2, 1000) [Routing],
```

I tried the code you gave above and it provided the same results with the `DISTINCT` reordering the data but without `DISTINCT` not removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY` will work:

```
stuff((select ','+ x3.Routing AS [text()] --This DISTINCT reorders the routes once concatenated.
 --SELECT  ','+ x3.Routing  AS [text()] --This without the DISTINCT does not remove duplicates.
        from vw_Routing x3
        where x3.CableID = c.CableId
        group by x3.Routing
        order by min(x3.id)
        for XML PATH ('')
       ), 1, 1, '') as [Routing],
```

I also replaced the `SUBSTRING()` with `STUFF()`.  The latter is more standard for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

To https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff
Unfortunately, that did not work.  It gave me the same result as my select statement; that is, no dups but reordering data.

HOWEVER, I found the correct answer earlier today:

I figured it out finally!!  I still have to get implement it within the other code and add the new Cable Area code, but the hard part it over!!!!!

I am going to post the following to the forums so that they know not to work on it .... I was writing this to send to my friend for his help, but I figured it out myself before I sent it.

I started with raw, comma separated data in the records of a table … the data is from another source.  I had to remove some of the information from each value, so I used the following code to split it up and manipulate it:
[Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M3QZ.png)

Once that was done, I had to put the manipulated data back in the same form in the same order and with no duplicates.  So I needed a SELECT DISTINCT.  When I used the commented out SELECT DISTINCT below, it removed duplicates but it changed the order of the data which I could not have as it is Cable Tray Routing Data.  When I took out the SELECT DISTINCT, it kept correct order, but left duplicates.

Because I was using XML PATH, I had to change this code …… To this code so that I could use SELECT DISTINCT remove the duplicates:[Code2 and Code3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSfc5.jpg)

